# wxWidgets deprecated constructor

Tags: gcc, g++, wxwidgets, gcc5

I'm trying to compile following code using wxWidgets 3.0 library:

*foo.h*

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
  #include <wx/version.h>

  #if wxMAJOR_VERSION >= 3
    #pragma GCC diagnostic push
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations" //< I'm trying to disable warning
  #endif // wxMAJOR_VERSION >= 3

#endif // __GNUC__

#ifdef HAVE_VARIADIC_MACROS
  #undef HAVE_VARIADIC_MACROS //< this macro redefines in wx.h
#endif // HAVE_VARIADIC_MACROS

#include <wx/wx.h> //< deprecated constructor defined here

#ifdef __GNUC__
  #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif // __GNUC__
```

*foo.cpp*

```
#include "foo.h"
....
some_menu = new wxMenuItem( ... ); //< deprecated constructor
```

The constructor defined in file *wx/menuitem.h*
code:

```
#if WXWIN_COMPATIBILITY_2_8 //< defined
    // compatibility only, don't use in new code
    wxDEPRECATED_CONSTRUCTOR(
    wxMenuItem(wxMenu *parentMenu,
               int id,
               const wxString& text,
               const wxString& help,
               bool isCheckable,
               wxMenu *subMenu = NULL)
    );
#endif
```

Compiling with gcc 5.4.0, Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64:

```
    g++ -o foo.os -c -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0 -I/usr/include/wx-3.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -g3 -Wall -Werror
...
foo.cpp:83:109: error: 'wxMenuItem::wxMenuItem(...)' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious and best solution is to stop using the deprecated ctor, it's pretty simple to do, so why not?

Otherwise, I think (but I didn't test it) that you could also make it work with `#pragma`s, but you'd need to put them around *your* code using this ctor, because this is where the warning is generated, not around the declaration.

Finally, for completeness, you could also remove `-Werror` and live with the warning but this is, of course, not the best choice.